# IDA has insufficient permissions to use debug local applications on the Mac

Tags: ida

When I debug the local application, it indicates insufficient permissions. I try to use remote host127.0.01 in the pop-up window, but it is invalid. So what should I do

The tips are as follows:
Please run IDA with elevated permissions for local debugging

Comment: You don't say what version of IDA. IDA Free does not support remote debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You should run remote debugger in the Terminal application. If you IDA version is 7.1, the command will be (you'll have to enter your password):

```
sudo /Applications/IDA\ Pro\ 7.1/dbgsrv/mac_server64
Password:
IDA Mac OS X 64-bit remote debug server(MT) v1.25. Hex-Rays (c) 2004-2019
Listening on 0.0.0.0:23946...
```

Now, you can set "Debugger" -> "Switch Debugger" - select "Remote Mac OS X debugger", then "Debugger" -> "Process options" and type:

"Hostname" "localhost"

"Port" "23946"

See also official document: https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/freefiles/remotedbg.pdf